# Messed up layout with isotope in a responsive web design

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope in a responsive web design at http://www.gablabelle.com and the layout is good on page load but it gets messed up when resizing window. I can't figure out what's wrong after reviewing my script file.

The weird thing is that the layout gets in place at some point.

Please take a look at this video: http://www.visualise.ca/files/videos/isotope02.mov

Also added an example at http://jsfiddle.net/CNb7r/

I've tried with the two different jQuery scripts

1st)

```
    var $container = $("#stream");
    var $window = $(window);
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.isotope({
            animationEngine: "best-available",
            itemSelector : "article.post",
            masonry: {
            columnWidth: 300,
            gutterWidth: 30
            },
            onLayout: function(){
                forceLoad();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    html_height = $container.height();
                    $("#sidebar").height(html_height - 30);
                }, 500);
            }    
        });
    });
    $window.smartresize(function(){
        var windowSize = $window.width();
        var masonryOpts;
        // update sizing options 
        if (windowSize > 1199) {
            masonryOpts = {
                columnWidth: 300,
                gutterWidth: 30
            };
        } else if (windowSize < 1200 && windowSize > 979) {
            masonryOpts = {
                columnWidth: 240,
                gutterWidth: 20
            };
        } else if (windowSize < 768) {
            masonryOpts = {
                columnWidth: windowSize / 2,
                gutterWidth: 1
            };
        } else {
            masonryOpts = {
                columnWidth: 186,
                gutterWidth: 20
            };
        }
        $container.isotope({
            masonry: masonryOpts
        }).isotope('reLayout');
    }).smartresize();
```

and the 2nd)

```
$(window).smartresize(function(){       
        var $windowSize = $(window).width();
        if ($windowSize > 1199) {
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    animationEngine: "best-available",
                    itemSelector : "article.post",
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 300,
                        gutterWidth: 30
                    },
                    onLayout: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            html_height = $container.height();
                            $("#sidebar").height(html_height - 30);
                        }, 500);
                    }       
                });
            });
        } else if ($windowSize < 1200 && $windowSize > 979) {
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    animationEngine: "best-available",
                    itemSelector : "article.post",
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 240,
                        gutterWidth: 20
                    },
                    onLayout: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            html_height = $container.height();
                            $("#sidebar").height(html_height - 20);
                        }, 500);
                    }       
                });
            });
        } else if ($windowSize < 768) {
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    animationEngine: "best-available",
                    itemSelector : "article.post",
                    resizable: false,
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: $windowSize / 2,
                        gutterWidth: 1
                    },
                    onLayout: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            html_height = $container.height();
                            $("#sidebar").height(html_height - 30);
                        }, 500);
                    }   
                });
            });
        } else {
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    animationEngine: "best-available",
                    itemSelector : "article.post",
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 186,
                        gutterWidth: 20
                    },
                    onLayout: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            html_height = $container.height();
                            $("#sidebar").height(html_height - 20);
                        }, 500);
                    }   
                });
            });
        };  
    }).smartresize();
```

If you disable Javascript, you'll see the responsive CSS is correct (no thumbnails will be displayed, only placeholders).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/271#issuecomment-8887060